# How can I create multiple cropped Media images without re-uploading them?

Tags: 8, media

Solutions that I've found allow to crop Media, type Image when I've uploaded an image, but the media entity is not yet created (on the "Add media" page).

I need to upload a large full image once (and use it in full format on some nodes), and then crop it differently when I select it in different content types (to display small "zoomed" parts of the full image). So I need a manual crop to appear when I select a Media of type Image from a Media library. It can appear in Entity browser or on the node page.

Other solution is that I can create cropped images in advance being in my media library (`/admin/content/media`) or when adding a media (`/media/add/image`). The idea is that I do not want to reupload the image and add new title and alt.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you familiar with 
[Image Styles](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-image-style-create.html)
and [image_style_warmer contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_style_warmer)?

Comment: What cropping modules are you using? With crop and image_widget_crop, you can set up multiple crop types, configure different image styles that each uses the desired crop type and then you can basically do as many crop configurations as you want

Comment: I used image_widget_crop, but the problem is that I needed to upload a new image to have it's cropped version, I could not use an existing one. And also the manual crop area appeared everywhere, even there where I did not need crop.

I use Image Styles, sure. The problem of it and image_style_warmer contrib module is that they can create styles where crop is the same for all images. I need to crop manually sometimes in the center, sometimes in some corner etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Install Crop API and [Image Widget Crop modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_widget_crop)
2. Configure Image Widget Crop as explained in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIcM5zxf0x8), for Image field situated in `Structure > Media types > Image`. The image style for this Image field should contain no effects.
3. There where you want to use cropped image, select the style for it (in content type, for example) that contain "Manual crop" effect and, if you need, "Crop and Scale effect" (to display square thumbnails in listings, for example).
4. There where you want to use full umage, select the style for it that contain no "Manual crop" effect.

How to use images:

1. Upload a large full image, crop manually the interesting part
2. Use the same image there where you need it cropped and there where you need it full. It will be displayed differently on front.

Note: if you try to clone the Image entity (for example with [Entity Clone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone)), it will not help because the clone Image entity and the original Image entity will apply the same crop.